# React Native changes to code have no affect on emulator app?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am running through [this tutorial](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/react-native-tutorial-part-1-hello-react), and have gotten as far as getting the text to display on my emulator screen (run through Android Studio).

[image: emulated app]

I have replaced the code in `App.js` with the sample code mentioned on the tutorial. The tutorial says to place this text in android.index.js, but I cannot find that file anywhere in the project. The code that used to be in App.js, at any rate, contains the text displayed in the emulator.

The code in App.js before my edit is as follows:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
   instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

And, after I replace it, it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

class ReactCalculator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Hello, React!</Text>
          </View>
        )
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactCalculator', () => ReactCalculator);
```

However, even if I uninstall the app from my emulator and reinstall it with `react-native run-android`, the text remains the same as in the above picture. It should be changing to be a css-less "Hell React" in the upper left hand corner of the screen, both according to my own understanding of the code and the tutorial.

From the base project directory, the command `ls -R | grep index.android` returns the following. I do not have an index.android.js anywhere in the project.

```
index.android.bundle
index.android.bundle
```

### EDIT I

I surrounded the  with a  in the code above. Also, the index.js file looks like this:

```
/** @format */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import ReactCalculator from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I changed the second line from `import App from './App';` to `import ReactCalculator from './App';`, but both ways the app does not change.

Comment: I did. Even uninstalling and reinstalling the app failed to make a change. Editing to add more relevant info.

Comment: did you add View back in to the import where Text is?

Comment: also, i think somewhere inside of the react project, it points to App.js. so if you removed app.js.... (im not a react dev)

Comment: @DroiDev I edited the code above to reflect the current state. Also, I am making edits to App.js, not removing it. The file still has the same name.

Comment: u dont need to import the ReactCalculator in... Plus, you would import it like import ReactCalculator from './reactcalculator.js' and then you can use it... but if you are using App.js, you can send a route from App.js to another class... this way you are not messing around with app.js i think u need to learn more about it.

Comment: So I shouldn't change App.js? Just import from a different js file? But then I still don't understand why changing App.js doesn't break the project. It just doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in rebuilding the app. It turns out that the command `react-native run-android` would build the app the first time it was run, but not any subsequent times. I've written a bash script with the following code to force a rebuild on an app every time it's run.

Put this in a bash script and run from the project directory

```
sudo rm -rf android/ ios/ #Delete Android and ios folders first...
react-native eject
react-native upgrade //rebuilds android/ios folders
react-native link
react-native run-android &2> /dev/null
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk # Change this if it's not where you sdk is.
dir=$(pwd)
cd -
echo "sdk.dir=$dir" > android/local.properties
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
react-native run-android
```